# How create RouteLink with custom routes registered in route config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes, routeconfig

Im having this routes in RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminGroupsEdit",
                url: "admin/groups/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Group", action = "Edit" }
            );
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminGroupsEditStudent",
                url: "admin/groups/{id}/students/{studentid}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Edit" }
            );
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminGroupsCreateStudent",
                url: "admin/groups/{groupId}/students/create-student",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Create" }
            );
```

When im on page with iri:

> admin/groups/1

there is a RouteLink:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Add", routeName: "AdminGroupsCreateStudent", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

But when i clicked on it asp.net going to route with name "AdminGroupsEdit".
How can i create RouteLink to go to route with name "AdminGroupsCreateStudent"? If i need to pass groupId throw routeValues so how can i get it from Uri?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues I can see with the way your currently routing so I've detailed below along with recommendations to resolve.

1. In your example, all that the routing engine is able to understand is that your attempting to create a Url to the route name `AdminGroupsCreateStudent`. The routing engine is able to confirm it has a route with the name `AdminGroupsCreateStudent`, but then when trying to match the route values against the parameters, it's unable to continue as you've attempted to pass `null` and this route needs a parameter of `groupId` in order to succeed so it returns the route referring to the page your on.
2. By creating a parameter mid-way into the Url, the routing engine
   expects a value for the route to render successfully. Sadly even attempting to assign the `groupId` parameter with the value `UrlParameter.Optional`, You would still end up with the same issue during runtime as once again the engine would is unable to do anything with a `null` parameter in the middle of Url as it cleverly knows it would break the link and is the reason why parameters are placed at the end or have default values.

My recommendation's would be to do either of the following:

Add `groupId` to the end of the routes Url and set the default value to `UrlParameter.Optional`.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminGroupsCreateStudent",
                url: "admin/groups/students/create-student/{groupId}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Create", groupId = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Or if you need to have this Url in place, then just set a default value for `groupId` to handle the `null` and then manage the logic for this value in the `Create` action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "AdminGroupsCreateStudent",
                url: "admin/groups/{groupId}/students/create-student",
                defaults: new { controller = "Student", action = "Create", groupId = 0 } //0 == Unknown
            );
```